# Creating a weighted sum of values from different tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a list of students whose behaviour is statistically worst across each of our school's year groups.

We have a table named `students`.

We then have behavioural `flags` and `alerts`, plus `sanctions`.

However, different categories of flag/alert/sanction are deemed more serious than others. These are stored with labels in their respective `_categories` table, e.g. `flag_categories` and `sanction_categories`. The `flag` table will then have a column called `Category_ID` (`alerts` is a bit different as it's just a `Type` field with 'A', 'C', 'P' and 'S' values).

If I want to look at data which shows our highest-flagged students in a specific year group, I'd run this query:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(stu.Firstname, " ", stu.Surname) AS `Student`,
  COUNT(f.ID) AS `Flags`
FROM `students` stu
LEFT JOIN `flags` f ON f.Student_ID = stu.id
WHERE stu.Year_Group = 9
GROUP BY stu.id
ORDER BY `Flags` DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

If I wanted to show our students with the most Crisis alerts in a specific year group, I'd run this query:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(stu.Firstname, " ", stu.Surname) AS `Student`,
  COUNT(f.ID) AS `Flags`
FROM `students` stu
LEFT JOIN `flags` f ON f.Student_ID = stu.id
WHERE stu.Year_Group = 9
AND f.Category_ID = 10
GROUP BY stu.id
ORDER BY `Flags` DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

If I want to find how many Late or Mobile flags a student has, and perhaps add these together (with weightings), I can run the following query:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(stu.Firstname, " ", stu.Surname) AS `Student`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN f.Category_ID = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Late Flags`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN f.Category_ID = 12 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) AS `Mobile Flags`,
  ## not sure about this line below... is there a nicer way of doing it? `Late Flags` isn't recognised as a field apparently
  ## so I can't just do ( `Late Flags` + `Mobile Flags` )
  (SUM(CASE WHEN f.Category_ID = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN f.Category_ID = 12 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END)) AS `Points`
FROM `flags` f
LEFT JOIN `students` stu ON f.Student_ID = stu.id
WHERE stu.Year_Group = 9
GROUP BY stu.id
ORDER BY `Points` DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

What I don't understand is how I would do this across myriad tables. I need to be able to weight:

- Late (`flags`, `Category_ID = 10`), Absconded (`flags`, `Category_ID = 15`) and Community flags (`flags`, `Category_ID = 13`) plus Safeguarding alerts (`alerts`, `Type = 'S'`) are all worth 1 point
- Behavioural flags (`flags`, `Category_ID IN (1, 7, 8)`) are worth 2 points
- Process alerts (`alerts`, `Type = 'P'`) and detention sanctions (`sanctions`, `Category_ID = 1`) are worth 3 points

So on and so forth. That's far from an exhaustive list but I've included enough variables to help me get my head round a multi-table weighted sum.

The outcome I'm looking for is just 2 columns - student's name and weighted points.

So, according to the bullet points above, if a student has received 2 Late flags (1 point each) and 1 Process alert (3 points), the output should just say `Joe Bloggs` and `5`.

Can anyone help me to understand how I can get these weighted values from different tables into one SUM'd output for each student?

**[edit] SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/449218/1/0**

Comment: Load up a bunch of data on a share somewhere. Some grabs your zip or sqlfiddle and takes a look.

Comment: Yeah probably a good plan @Drew. I'll do that now.

Comment: I've added an SQL fiddle now. It's not all of the data (missed off the sanctions table and cut quite a few fields) but it should be enough for an answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/449218/1/0 (and edited into OP).

Comment: Could you please show your expected output for this given input set in a tabular format? It will be easier to catch. @dunc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, I am not doing this for the bounty. Please give to someone else.

This could be done with a few `LEFT JOIN`s of derived tables. Note you did not supply the sanctions table. But the below would appear to be well illustrative. So I created a temp table. It would seem to allow for maximum flexibility without overcomplicating a larger left join notion that might be hard to debug. Afterall, you said your real querying will be much more complicated than this. As such, build out the temp table structure more.

This loads a tmp table up with default 0's for the students in the "passed by parameter *Student Year*" to a stored procedure. Two updates are performed. Then selects for a result set.

**Schema / Load:**

```
create schema s38741386; -- create a test database
use s38741386;

CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  `Firstname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Surname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Year_Group` int(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

# STUDENT INSERTS
INSERT INTO `students`
  (`id`, `Firstname`, `Surname`, `Year_Group`)
VALUES
  (201, 'Student', 'A', 9),
  (202, 'Student', 'B', 9),
  (203, 'Student', 'C', 9),
  (204, 'Student', 'D', 9),
  (205, 'Student', 'E', 9);

CREATE TABLE `alert` (
  `ID` int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  `Staff_ID` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `Datetime_Raised` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Room_Label` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Type` enum('A','C','P','Q','S') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'A=Absconded, C=Crisis, P=Process, Q=Quiet, S=Safeguarding',
  `Details` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Responder` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Datetime_Responded` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Room_ID` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'will be linked to internal room id.',
  `Status` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'O:ngoing, R:esolved'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

# ALERT INSERTS
INSERT INTO `alert`
  (`ID`, `Staff_ID`, `Datetime_Raised`, `Room_Label`, `Type`, `Details`, `Responder`, `Datetime_Responded`, `Room_ID`, `Status`)
VALUES
  (1, '101', '2016-08-04 00:00:00', NULL, 'P', NULL, '103', '2016-08-04 00:00:01', '15', 'R'),
  (2, '102', '2016-08-04 00:00:00', NULL, 'P', NULL, '103', '2016-08-04 00:00:01', '15', 'R'),
  (3, '102', '2016-08-04 00:00:00', NULL, 'P', NULL, '103', '2016-08-04 00:00:01', '15', 'R'),
  (4, '101', '2016-08-04 00:00:00', NULL, 'P', NULL, '103', '2016-08-04 00:00:01', '15', 'R');

CREATE TABLE `alert_students` (
  `ID` int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  `Alert_ID` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `Student_ID` int(6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

# ALERT_STUDENT INSERTS
INSERT INTO `alert_students`
  (`ID`, `Alert_ID`, `Student_ID`)
VALUES
  (1, '1', '201'),
  (2, '1', '202'),
  (3, '2', '201'),
  (4, '3', '202'),
  (5, '4', '203'),
  (6, '5', '204');

CREATE TABLE `flags` (
  `ID` int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  `Staff_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Student_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Category_ID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


# ALERT INSERTS
-- TRUNCATE TABLE flags;
INSERT INTO `flags`
  (`ID`, `Staff_ID`, `Student_ID`, `Datetime`, `Category_ID`)
VALUES
  (1, '101', '201', '2016-08-04 00:00:01', 10),
  (2, '102', '202', '2016-08-04 00:00:02', 12),
  (3, '102', '203', '2016-08-04 00:00:03', 10),
  (4, '101', '204', '2016-08-04 00:00:04', 13),
  (5, '102', '202', '2016-08-04 00:00:02', 12),
  (6, '102', '203', '2016-08-04 00:00:03', 10),
  (7, '101', '204', '2016-08-04 00:00:04', 13),
  (8, '102', '202', '2016-08-04 00:00:02', 10),
  (9, '102', '203', '2016-08-04 00:00:03', 10),
  (10, '101', '204', '2016-08-04 00:00:04', 7),
  (11, '101', '204', '2016-08-04 00:00:07', 8),
  (12, '101', '204', '2016-08-04 00:00:08', 1),
  (13, '101', '204', '2016-08-04 00:00:09', 8);
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS rptSM_by_year;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE rptSM_by_year
(   pSY INT -- parameter student year
)
BEGIN


    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmpStudentMetrics;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpStudentMetrics
    (   `StudentId` int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
        LateFP INT NOT NULL,
        MobiFP INT NOT NULL,
        AbscFP INT NOT NULL,
        CommFP INT NOT NULL,
        SafeAP INT NOT NULL,
        BehaFP INT NOT NULL,
        ProcAP INT NOT NULL
    )ENGINE=InnoDB;

    INSERT tmpStudentMetrics (StudentId,LateFP,MobiFP,AbscFP,CommFP,SafeAP,BehaFP,ProcAP)
    SELECT id,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    FROM students
    WHERE Year_Group = pSY;

    UPDATE tmpStudentMetrics tmp
    JOIN
    (   SELECT
          stu.id,
          SUM(CASE WHEN f.Category_ID = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `LateFP`,
          SUM(CASE WHEN f.Category_ID = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `AbscFP`,
          SUM(CASE WHEN f.Category_ID = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `CommFP`,
          SUM(CASE WHEN f.Category_ID = 12 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) AS `MobiFP`,
          SUM(CASE WHEN f.Category_ID IN (1,7,8) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) AS `BehaFP`
        FROM `flags` f
        LEFT JOIN `students` stu ON f.Student_ID = stu.id
        WHERE stu.Year_Group = pSY
        GROUP BY stu.id
    ) xDerived
    ON xDerived.id=tmp.StudentId
    SET tmp.LateFP=xDerived.LateFP,
    tmp.AbscFP=xDerived.AbscFP,
    tmp.CommFP=xDerived.CommFP,
    tmp.MobiFP=xDerived.MobiFP,
    tmp.BehaFP=xDerived.BehaFP;

    UPDATE tmpStudentMetrics tmp
    JOIN
    (   SELECT
          stu.id,
          SUM(CASE WHEN a.Type = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `SafeAP`,
          SUM(CASE WHEN a.Type = 'P' THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) AS `ProcAP`
        FROM `alert_students` als
        JOIN `alert` a
        ON a.ID=als.Alert_ID
        JOIN `students` stu 
        ON stu.id=als.Student_ID and stu.Year_Group = pSY
        GROUP BY stu.id
    ) xDerived
    ON xDerived.id=tmp.StudentId
    SET tmp.SafeAP=xDerived.SafeAP,
    tmp.ProcAP=xDerived.ProcAP;

    -- SELECT * FROM tmpStudentMetrics; -- check detail

    SELECT stu.id, 
    CONCAT(stu.Firstname, " ", stu.Surname) AS `Student`, 
    tmp.LateFP+tmp.MobiFP+tmp.AbscFP+tmp.CommFP+tmp.SafeAP+tmp.BehaFP+tmp.ProcAP AS `Points` 
    FROM `students` stu 
    JOIN tmpStudentMetrics tmp 
    ON tmp.StudentId=stu.id 
    WHERE stu.`Year_Group` = pSY 
    ORDER BY stu.id; 

    -- SELECT * FROM tmpStudentMetrics; -- check detail
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmpStudentMetrics;
    -- TEMP TABLES are connection based. Explicityly dropped above for safety when done.
    -- Depends on your connection type and life-span otherwise.
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Test:**

```
call rptSM_by_year(9);
+-----+-----------+--------+
| id  | Student   | Points |
+-----+-----------+--------+
| 201 | Student A |      7 |
| 202 | Student B |     11 |
| 203 | Student C |      6 |
| 204 | Student D |     10 |
| 205 | Student E |      0 |
+-----+-----------+--------+
```

**Cleanup:**

```
drop schema s38741386; -- drop the test database
```

Answer (score 1):

Think all you have asked can be done with a subquery and a couple of sub-SELECTs:

```
SELECT `Student`,
       `Late Flags` * 1
     + `Absconded Flags` * 1
     + `Community Flags` * 1
     + `Safeguarding Alerts Flags` * 1
     + `Behavioural flags` * 2
     + `Process Alerts Flags` * 3 AS `Total Points`
FROM
(
SELECT
  CONCAT(stu.Firstname, " ", stu.Surname) AS `Student`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN f.Category_ID = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Late Flags`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN f.Category_ID = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Mobile Flags`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN f.Category_ID = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Absconded Flags`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN f.Category_ID = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Community Flags`,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `alert` a JOIN `alert_students` ast ON ast.`Alert_ID` = a.`ID`
   WHERE ast.`Student_ID` = stu.`id` AND a.`Type` = 'S') AS `Safeguarding Alerts Flags`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN f.Category_ID IN (1, 7, 8) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Behavioural flags`,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `alert` a JOIN `alert_students` ast ON ast.`Alert_ID` = a.`ID`
   WHERE ast.`Student_ID` = stu.`id` AND a.`Type` = 'P') AS `Process Alerts Flags`
FROM `students` stu
LEFT JOIN `flags` f ON f.Student_ID = stu.id
WHERE stu.Year_Group = 9
GROUP BY stu.id
LIMIT 0, 20
) subq
ORDER BY `Total Points` DESC;
```

The above query includes everything you mentioned apart from sanctions (as your original SQL Fiddle demo didn't include this table).

#### Demo

An updated fiddle with the above query is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/449218/39.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [union all](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union_all.php)

Basically you create all your individual queries for each table and connect them all together using union all.

Here is an example, I used your student table twice but you would change the second one to what ever other table you want. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/449218/22/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `LEFT JOINS`:

```
   SELECT CONCAT(stu.firstname,' ', stu.surname) student,
          COALESCE(f_group.weight_sum,0) + COALESCE(a_group.weight_sum,0) + COALESCE(s_group.weight_sum,0) points
     FROM students stu
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT s_f.id, SUM(f.category_id IN (10,13,15) + 2 * f.category_id IN (1,7,8)) weight_sum
         FROM students s_f
         JOIN flags f
           ON f.student_id = s_f.id
          AND f.category_id IN (1,7,8,10,13,15) 
        WHERE s_f.year_group = :year_group
     GROUP BY s_f.id           
          ) f_group
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT s_a.id, 3 * COUNT(*) weight_sum
         FROM students s_a
         JOIN alerts a
           ON a.student_id = s_a.id
          AND a.type = 'P' 
        WHERE s_a.year_group = :year_group
     GROUP BY s_a.id           
          ) a_group
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT s_s.id, COUNT(*) weight_sum
         FROM students s_s
         JOIN sanctions s
           ON s.student_id = s_s.id
          AND s.category_id = 1
        WHERE s_s.year_group = :year_group
     GROUP BY s_s.id           
          ) s_group
    WHERE stu.year_group = :year_group
 ORDER BY points DESC
    LIMIT 0, 20
```

BUT if you have full access to the DB I'd be putting those weights in the respective categories and types, which will simplify the logic.